# JavaFX, Gradle and JPMS reading resources always returns null

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, javafx, java-platform-module-system

I am trying to read resources for my JavaFX application but it only works, if the `module-info` is not defined. If the `module-info` is defined, I always receive `null` for the following code:

```java
// Replace ... with a specific path, for example: JavaFX_Logo.png
String url = getClass().getResource("...").toExternalForm();
```

Source tried:

- [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other)
- https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/890#issuecomment-603289940

MWE:
I made an minimal working example in github if someone is interested to see the output. I am using the IDE called IntelliJ and build tool called Gradle (Kotlin DSL).

- https://github.com/Zentox/ExampleFX

Example code:

```java
package app;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class App extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Pane pane = new Pane(root);
        String url = getClass().getResource("JavaFX_Logo.png").toExternalForm(); // Returns NPE, because getResource return null
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(url);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1024, 768);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

modul-info:

```java
module ExampleFX.main {
    requires javafx.graphics;

    exports app;
}
```

Resources to the image: `src/main/resources/app/JavaFX_Logo.png`

Build structure:

```
build
 ┣ classes
 ┃ ┗ java
 ┃ ┃ ┗ main
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ app
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ App.class
 ┣ distributions
 ┃ ┣ ExampleFX-1.0-SNAPSHOT.tar
 ┃ ┗ ExampleFX-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
 ┣ generated
 ┃ ┗ sources
 ┃ ┃ ┣ annotationProcessor
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ java
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ main
 ┃ ┃ ┗ headers
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ java
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ main
 ┣ libs
 ┃ ┗ ExampleFX-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
 ┣ resources
 ┃ ┗ main
 ┃ ┃ ┗ app
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ JavaFX_Logo.png
 ┣ scripts
 ┃ ┣ ExampleFX
 ┃ ┗ ExampleFX.bat
 ┗ tmp
 ┃ ┣ compileJava
 ┃ ┃ ┗ source-classes-mapping.txt
 ┃ ┗ jar
 ┃ ┃ ┗ MANIFEST.MF
```

Edit:

- Added `modul-info`

Comment: Did you create your own module-info.java or is it generated by gradle?

Comment: I've created my own. I forgot to add it on the github repositoy and on my question. I added it now.

Comment: I'm not sure the `org.openjfx.javafxplugin` is compatible with the module handling added in Gradle 6.4. Does the problem occur if you remove the JavaFX plugin and add the JavaFX dependencies manually? Note you need the appropriate classifier (e.g. `org.openjfx:javafx-base:<version>:win` for Windows); unfortunately, the classifier breaks transitive dependency resolution in Gradle so you'll have to add each JavaFX dependency explicitly.

Comment: Sorry for the late response because I had some upcoming exams. Your answer solved the problem. Thanks a lot!